# Dropbox SDK (iOS) has language issue with sign in?

Tags: ios, authentication, sdk, dropbox-api

The problem is the app has its own language according to the device settings. But when I call "sign in" view of Dropbox (method `linkFromController:`) it shows a dialog according to the language in the user account settings.

Does anybody know how to force this view to be shown in the same language the app has?

Comment: No, the Dropbox iOS Core SDK doesn't offer an option for overriding this when using `linkFromController`.

Comment: but in the same time this sdk is represented with compiled framework and raw sources. Now I try to check these sources to make it workable